# Github Action Self-hosted machine Secrets not being passed to program

Tags: github, github-actions, devops, github-actions-self-hosted-runners, github-secret

I have a Github action running on a self-hosted VM; I want to build and run a go executable in the workflow, and the program itself can run shell commands using Go's [os.exec](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec) command.

I have tried to pass the secrets as env variables, but noticed that they are not being propagated to the Go program at all. Relevant part of YML file:

```yaml
my_job:
    name: example
    runs-on: [self-hosted, mylabel]
    env:
      working-directory: src
      ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.ACCESS_KEY }}
      SECRET_KEY: ${{ secrets.SECRET_KEY }}
    ...
    ... Run Go Program
```

When printing the env variable in the Go program, it returns nothing. This is only happening with self-hosted runners, Github runners have no issue. What could be causing this?

Comment: The way you're setting up environment variables is proper. Make sure you're running Go application inside the same job where you declared and initialized the environment variables. 

    access_key := os.Getenv(ACCESS_KEY)

You should be able to get env value.

Comment: @DayanandaDR That's the issue; doing os.Getenv returns an empty string, which means the env variable cannot be found by the Go program at all.

Comment: How do you run the Go program in your workflow? Is it a binary you're building previously, or just a go file you're running directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to this; the Go binary was being run as `sudo` and the secrets were not set in sudo context. Running the go binary without sudo will allow us to access the secrets.